# How to get each id in pointIds of a cell?

Tags: python, vtk

In python, I want to get every id from point Ids of a cell.

How can I do it?

Polygon is Triangle case..

Thank you.

```
polygons = vtk.vtkCellArray()
polygons = poly.GetPolys())
n_cells = poly.GetNumberOfCells()
for i in range(n_cells):   
    cell = poly.GetCell(i)
    idList = vtk.vtkIdList() 
    idList = cell.GetPointIds()
    id <== idList # I want to know the way.
```

Comment: What goes wrong with `pids = cell.GetPointIds()` ?

Comment: └ I changed typo. :)

Comment: Still does not understand. `idList` should be a list containing the ids. So what goes wrong ?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for `idList.GetId(k)`?